# Method called on BringSubviewToFront?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, switch-statement, subview

Is there a method that is called on the view when using bringSubviewToFront?

I have a container view where I switch between a list view and map view. I want the map to zoom in to a location when I switch to it, but since the map view is already loaded before I switch to it, the viewDidLoad method is not called when I switch. How would I get around this? Is there a method that is called when switching within a container view? If I understand correctly the embed segue is called on loading of the container view?

Anyway, any help would be much appreciated. If I need to post code, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: So you have two `UIViewController`s added as subviews?

Comment: Yes, one is a table view, the other map view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this method :-**
 As you are triggering a new view layout event, so the following method get fired:-

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    //this method will fire while you add or switch view or bringSubviewToFront in the View Controller 

}
```

Just put a breakpoint, and check!